# Starting a new paragraph after ending the old one with a question

Tags: paragraphs

An example might involve ending one paragraph with the words

> ... So why is ___ so high?

and then starting the next paragraph with something like this:

> If we take a look at __ ...

Is it acceptable to begin a new paragraph immediately after asking a question in the previous paragraph?

Comment: It is unclear what your question is.

Comment: question was answered by Dog Lover

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with asking a question at the end of a paragraph and then answering it in the next paragraph.

Have a look at [this](http://www.clearwriter.com/cleartips/powerfulparagraphs/3-6.htm) article.

> Questions suggest answers. Posing a question at the end  of a paragraph signals the reader to look for your answer in the next.

Comment: @tam No problem - glad it was helpful!